# I want to add text in top and bottom of angular-barcode like alternative text

Tags: angularjs, canvas, barcode

I want to add text in top and bottom of angular-barcode directive like alternative text. I have already added alternative text in the bottom but want to add in the top also.

angular-barcode uses JsBarcode library. I am using canvas rendering in angular-barcode directive. I tried to add text based on this [example](https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode/issues/225)  by creating canvas object but it didnt work. If anyone has an idea how can I solve it. Please suggest me. Your help is greatly appreciated

I want to add text like [this](https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode/issues/225) in angular-barcode

[refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50216077/unable-to-add-new-canvas-element-with-an-existing-one)

Comment: Do you want the top text compulsory to be part of barcode canvas?

Comment: Yes I want to add barcode scanning value in bottom and alternative text in top 
Please give me any suggestion how can I do this

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If your canvas is not writing to HTML the synchronous solution provided by your link will not work.

A better solution here would be to use JSBarcode's text option to overwrite the default text displayed under the barcode.

Here is a snippet of code I've written for this problem.

```
import * as JsBarcode from 'jsbarcode';
import { Canvas } from 'canvas';

...

const canvas = new Canvas(400, 400);
const barcode = "11011011";
const displayText = "My Custom Text Here";

JsBarcode(canvas, barcode, {
            flat: true,
            text: displayText
            textPosition: "top" // decide whether to display the text above or below the barcode.
});

// [Your method of writing the barcode]
```

This will replace the default text of under the barcode but when you scan the barcode the entered value would be read. In this case the entered value is the variable `barcode`.

Checkout the official docs on this here -> https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode/wiki/Options#text